# node.js perform http request with custom request method

Tags: node.js, http

I need to write maximum lightweight application using node.js, that connects to the different server, and handles stream respose from it. In curl, i can do this with following command:

`curl -X MYOWNMETHOD http://myserver/`

I found that it was implemented: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6422
But how is it possible to perform such request without additional middleware? Perhaps someone has did smth similar?

I've tried to use smth like this, but callback is not being executed, app just hangs.. have no idea why. If i use GET request on any website - that works. If i use custom request - socket hangs. If i use curl -X to access server - that also works.

var net = require('net');

```
var options = {
    method : 'OWNMETHOD',
    host : 'someserver',
    port : 80,
    user : 'test',
    password : 'test',
};

var client = net.connect({port: options.port, host: options.host}, function(){
    console.log('client connected');
    client.write(
        options.method + ' / HTTP/1.1\r\n' + 
        'Authorization: Basic ' + new Buffer(options.user + ':' + options.password).toString('base64') + '\r\n' + 
        'User-Agent: sexy/7.26.0\r\n' + 
        'Host: ' + options.host + '\r\n' +
        'Accept: */*\r\n' // should be TWO \r\n to make this work everywhere
    );
});

// Fires only for GET method
client.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('data');
  //console.log(data.toString());
  //client.end();
});

client.on('end', function() {
  console.log('client disconnected');
});

client.on('timeout', function() {
  console.log('timeout');
});

client.on('close', function() {
  console.log('closed');
});
```

**UPD:** Found the mistake: i forgot to add second \r\n to headers. Now it works fine.

Comment: Can you try your request with the full `var req = http.requrest...`, `req.on('error'...` and `req.end` in the example [in the node docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)?

Comment: Hmm.. i've got successful reponse with GET request now, but not for custom method.. will update code shortly

Comment: Does the error event on `http.request` (I know you're using `net` now) send anything when you make a request with your custom method? Does `res.end()`ing the request help?

Comment: @MichaelTang nope! that's i was lost. I found my mistake. I forgot to add seconf \r\n to headers... I am worst web developer in the world! Sorry for stupid question :(

Comment: Nice, verbose logging always is helpful during development.